# Sync Google sheets with Google Calendar, and blank cells in ss prevented subsequent events from being created

Tags: google-apps-script, synchronization

I'm very new to coding and running into problems.
I'm trying to sync my Google sheet to create All Day events on two separate GCal (so we can toggle between them) and experiencing a few issues.
1: If data is missing from a cell, any rows below that are ignored and no events created for them, even when those do have data.
2: Every time I deploy the code, it creates duplicate events. I would like it to create events only for edits.
3: The Debug feature tells me there is something wrong with my second iteration of the function createCalendarEvent to create events on the second calendar. But the code is the same as the first, so I'm not sure what is wrong.
Additionally, we have a different spreadsheet for each quarter of the year. Is SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet really the best term to use as we will have different "active sheets"? How do I ensure events from all 4 tabs of the Google sheet pull into the calendar.

ss snippet example. This is for a training calendar. Sometimes we have both a lesson and an article on the same topic that post on separate dates, but we liked having that info all on the one row in the ss, hence the two columns for post dates and checkboxes in the ss to show what type of training it is (lesson or article).

| lesson post date | article post date | event ID | lesson checkbox | article checkbox | project status | title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/11/2022 | null |  | checked | null | in progress | event title 1 |
| 7/18/2022 | null |  | checked | null | in progress | event title 2 |
| null | 7/15/2022 | null | checked | in progress | event title 3 |  |
| 7/23/2022 | null |  | checked | null | in progress | event title 4 |
| 7/23/2022 | 7/22/2022 | checked | checked | in progress | event title 5 |  |

Here is my code in Google AppsScript. I like this one because I understand it better, haha! But I am open to either options for the code or another format.
Any ideas on how to fix this version? Thanks in advance!!!

```js
function createCalendarEvent() {
  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let learningCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("CALENDARID");

  
  let schedule = spreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  schedule.splice(0,2);

schedule.forEach(function(entry) {
  learningCal.createAllDayEvent(entry[5], entry[0]);
});
  }

 function createCalendarEvent() {
  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let itkCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("CALENDARID");

  let schedule = spreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  schedule.splice(0,2);
  
  schedule.forEach(function(entry) {
  itkCal.createAllDayEvent(entry[5], entry[1]);
  });
 }
```

I found some code in the Stack database of questions that I adapted to create the eventID, but it isn't writing the event IDs on the Google sheet itself. So not sure if that is necessary. It seems to be working ok, but only if I put in placeholder dates on the events that are not yet assigned dates. We don't really want to do this step though, as this date can change frequently and we often will add a topic to the calendar before the actual event date is determined.

Also, the onOPen function isn't creating the button on the ss as I expected. I copied the code exactly from the instructions though, so I don't know how to solve!

```js
function onOpen(e) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Add to Cal')
  .addToUi();
}

function createCalendarEvent() {
  let calendarEventIdColumn = 3;
  let calendarEventIds = [];
  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let learningCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("####");
  let schedule = spreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  schedule.splice(0,2);

for (var x=0; x < schedule.length; x++) {
  var shifts = schedule[x];
  var Title = shifts[6];
  var DateOfEvent = shifts[0];
  var eventId = shifts [2];
  var event;

  if (eventId !== '') {
    event = learningCal.getEventById(eventId);
    event.setTitle(Title);
    event.setAllDayDate(DateOfEvent);
  }
  else {
    event = learningCal.createAllDayEvent(Title, DateOfEvent);

  }
  calendarEventIds.push([event.getId()]);
}
spreadsheet.getRange(calendarEventIdColumn, calendarEventIds.length, 1).setValues(calendarEventIds);

schedule.forEach(function(entry) {
  learningCal.createAllDayEvent(entry[6], entry[0]);
});
  }
```

Comment: 1.) You code breaks if the event can not be created, so it wont process further. 2.) How does the code knows it is edited? You get the event id back from the insert, store that in the sheet to check if you need to insert or update. 3.) Functions cannot have the same name. 5.) Loop over all the sheets. -- there are to many questions without any data to help you out the right way.

Comment: can you share a minimal reproducible example? It will be quite easy to solve all your problem (you will need to store the event id that you have created to prevent duplicates)

Comment: @RemcoE33 Oh that is helpful that I can't use the same function name. Thank you! I think I figured out the event ID code and added it in , but it isn't writing the code on my ss. Should it? Or can it just store that data in the code side and not have to "write" it on the ss? I'll update this question to add the code I found.

Comment: @MikeSteelson please let me know if the example ss snippet helps at all! Is there a way to write an "if else" clause that says, if null (cell is empty) check the row below? And can I use the same function to write to two Google calendars, or do I need to write two functions? SO instead perhaps, if column A is empty, check column B and write to Calendar Y instead of X? Could that solve this issue? Also not sure why the onOpen button isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom menus must contain at least one item.

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('⇩ Calendar ⇩')
    .addItem(' Add to Cal', 'createCalendarEvent')
    .addToUi();
}
```

[image]

Your corrected script

```
function createCalendarEvent() { 
  let calendarEventIdColumn = 3;
  let calendarEventIds = [];
  let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let learningCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("########"); // ##
  let schedule = spreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  schedule.splice(0, 2);

  schedule.forEach(function (entry) {
    var Title = entry[6];
    var DateOfEvent = entry[0];
    var EventId = entry[+calendarEventIdColumn - 1];
    var event;
    if (DateOfEvent == ''){
      calendarEventIds.push([''])
    }
    else if (EventId == '') {
      event = learningCal.createAllDayEvent(Title, new Date(DateOfEvent))
      calendarEventIds.push([event.getId()])
    }
    else {
      event = learningCal.getEventById(EventId);
      event.setTitle(Title);
      event.setAllDayDate(new Date(DateOfEvent));
      calendarEventIds.push([EventId])
    }
  });

  spreadsheet.getRange(3, calendarEventIdColumn, calendarEventIds.length, 1).setValues(calendarEventIds);

}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much! it is still having a few issues and I'm getting an error around the else if statement. The debugger just tells me the "else" is unexpected. any ideas? I'm been trying things but nothing is working.

Comment: here is my test file, change the calendarID and test https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10wl2KCK18z6kHvMYJMjkrldbdbrpjOChAWtFUt8PbFI/copy

Comment: Hi @MikeSteelson, thank you! A few more questions. Sorry for taking up so much of your time. 1) Now it isn't writing events to the calendar, and 2) it isn't populating the Events ID on the ss. Shouldn't it be? 3) And should I see the onOpen button on the spreadsheet? I only see it on the Apps Script page. 4), I copied the entire code (changed function name and entry #) from schedule.forEach through the spreadsheet.getRange line, for a separate event Cal, the one for articles, but none showed up. 5) will it still break if some of the cells are blank because those rows are for lessons?

Comment: go to the script editor, and try first to launch onOpen script when you are in the script editor, you will need to give authorization and then, i hope, everything will be fine. You will see the onOpen menu and yes you will see the event id when the event will be created inside the calendar.

Comment: thank you so much! Sorry I took a while to get back to you. It is all working now and I couldn't be more grateful for all your help and patience!